# Unable to eject Android phone

Tags: android, adb

When I try to eject my Android phone from my Windows 8 laptop (using the "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media" icon in the task bar) I get a "Problem Ejecting USB Composite Device" pop-up with the message:

> Windows can't stop your 'Android ADB Interface' device because a program is still using it. Close any programs that might be using the device, and then try again later.

I have a number of background and Windows processes running, but no apps, so any idea what could be causing this? One of the background processes is "abd (32 bit)", so should I just end that task? Or would it be better to just unplug the device and not worry about ejecting it first?

Comment: While the given answer addresses this specific case, a more general approach to solving these types of issues can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24460473/1290264

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Android uses ADB to communicate with physical devices and emulators. To properly disconnect your phone first stop the ADB server and then eject your device.

```
CD C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
adb kill-server
```

Then eject your device.

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).

Comment: Actually there's no need to stop adb - windows just doesn't know that.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Since posting this I've just been pulling the USB cable without using the "safely remove..." icon. So far it seems to be working just fine, so I hope that continues to be the case.

Comment: I was able to do this successfully in powershell in '19 with:   

  
`cd ~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools` . 
`./adb kill-server` 

I unplugged my device and ran 
`./adb start-server`  
to prep for my next coding session.

Answer (score 9):

As Andrew Halloran stated,  device can be safely removed if you first end  Android Debug Bridge adb.
That can be done using the Task Manager
[image]

Then click "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media"