# How force delete the file on hard drive in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, delete-file

I have a hard drive and this is a bad file on it! When I want to delete file windows says:

> "The file name you specified is not valid or too long.
>   Specify a different file name."

But the file not renamed! What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You cannot modify a resource when a running process has a handle to it.

The solution is to end all processes that have a handle to your resource. This is shown below.

---

**1.**
End all processes that have a handle to the resource:

*Start>>All Programs>>Accessories>>System Tools>>Resource Monitor* (or **Run** `resmon.exe`)

Search for the resource in the ***Associated Handles*** searchbox (circled in red). Look in the ***Handle Name*** column to see if any of the processes have a handle to the resource's URI and end those processes by right clicking and selecting ***End Process***.

[image]

**2.**
You should now be able to modify your resource, e.g. delete, rename, move, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Boot an Ubuntu live CD, navigate to the offending folder, and delete whatever files you want.  I tried all of the other solutions and none of them worked for me, but Ubuntu did.